# Checkbox select if exist data in database

Tags: php

I Have two tables as follow :

**Table 1 : product**

**Table 2 : product_add**

[image: prodct tables]

Now I want following output using PHP For Record Id = 3.

[image: Output]

I Will Try The Following Code :

```
<?php

$select = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE status = 1";
$query = mysql_query($select);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $s = "SELECT * FROM product_add WHERE status = 1 and product_id = '".$row["id"]."'";
    $q = mysql_query($s);
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
        echo $row["product_name"].'<input type="checkbox" '.($row["id"] == $r["product_id"] ? 'checked' : '').'>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: "**Now I want following output using PHP For Record Id = 3.**" Well, then good luck. :)

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Please before using stackoverflow make sure you have done the research

Comment: r u looking for QUERY + CODE? please share your code, if u tried anything

Comment: Code and Query ...

Comment: chk the answer, i hope this will help u.

Answer (score 0):

First of all stop using `mysql_*` extension it's deprecated and closed in PHP 7, you can use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Here is the example with MYSQLi Objected Oriented:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($YourServerName, $Yourusername, $Yourpassword, $Yourdbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// your query 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_add pa ON pa.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.status = 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // if record found
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) // using while loop
    {
    ?>
    <?=$row["product_name"]?>
    <input type="checkbox" <?=($row["record_id"] == 3 ? 'checked=""' : '')?>>
    <?php
    }
} 
else 
{
    // if record not exist.
}
?>
```

You can use JOIN for instead of using two queries inside the while loop. you can achieve your desired output by using `LEFT JOIN`.

---

If you still want to use your code, than note that, your condition is wrong:

```
$row["id"] == $r["product_id"]
```

This should be:

```
$row["record_id"] == 3
```

Comment: Thanks Bro... It Will Work but it will display first all selected checkbox record and then unchecked all... Can you display all the product in serial and checked if exist in table product_add like in output

Comment: @SachinSanchaniya: for this you can change your condition as i mentioned

Comment: If my answer help u don't forgot to accept it @SachinSanchaniya

Answer (score 0):

I Got the Answer As Follow

```
<?php

$select = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE status = 1";
$query = mysql_query($select);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $pid = $row['id'];
    $s = "SELECT * FROM product_add WHERE status = 1 and product_id = '$pid' and record_id = 3";
    $q = mysql_query($s);
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
    echo $row["product_name"].'<input type="checkbox" '.($pid == $r["product_id"] ? 'checked' : '').'>';

}

?>
```